# Geting Wordpress UserID and submitting with form

Tags: php, forms, wordpress

I went the easy way and used the program Web Form Builder for Mac to create a form for my website.  It actually is doing a decent job of making a nice form that uploads to mySQL, but I really want it to be able to find the userID of the logged in user to upload with the form.  That way I can correlate the submissions with the Wordpress user in the Database.

The user of my site has to be logged in to access the form, so getting the userID should always be possible.  I did find this on Wordpress which should help, but I am unsure how to add the code correctly and where to put it: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata

I am attaching the php for the forms down here.  Hopefully I can get some guidance, cause this would be a HUGE help for my site.

Idea Submission.php:

```
<?php

$scriptpath = substr( $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -4 );
$paths = explode ( DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $scriptpath );
$myName = end($paths);
require $scriptpath . '/fbapp/php/config.inc.php';


if( strtoupper( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) == 'POST' ) {

    $ctl = new FormController();
    $ctl->Dispatch();

} else {

    if( ! isset( $_GET['action'] ) )        $myPage->ReportStats( 'NotifyFormView' );
}

ob_start();

$myPage->Show();
ob_end_flush();

?>
```

Form.cfg.php (I have changed sensitive material & got rid of some unnecessary code for this post):

```
<?php exit(0); ?> { 
"settings":
{
    "data_settings" : 
    {
        "save_database" : 
        {
            "database" : "database",
            "is_present" : true,
            "password" : "password",
            "port" : 3306,
            "server" : "55.55.555.55",
            "tablename" : "Submissions",
            "username" : "username"
        },
        "save_file" : 
        {
            "filename" : "ideasubmissionform-results.csv",
            "is_present" : true
        },
        "save_sqlite" : 
        {
            "database" : "Idea Submission.dat",
            "is_present" : false,
            "tablename" : "Idea Submission"
        }
    },
    "email_settings" : 
    {
        "auto_response_message" : 
        {
            "custom" : 
            {
                "body" : "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>RegisterYourApp has received your files!!</title>\n</head>\n<body>\nHello [FirstName] [LastName],\n<br>\n   We really appreciate you signing up for our services and our excited to tell you that your app idea submission for [Title] has been received! Within the next 24 hours you'll be receiving confirmation of your file(s) being stamped and your unique hash code for the submitted files.  If you've submitted multiple files they will be stamped in one zip file so will contain a single hash code and confirmation e-mail.</p>\n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\nHere's a copy of what you submitted for your records:\n<p>\n[_form_results_]\n</body>\n</html>\n",
                "is_present" : true,
                "subject" : "We have received your submission!!"
            },
            "from" : "Info@MyDomain.com",
            "is_present" : true,
            "to" : "[email]"
        },
        "notification_message" : 
        {
            "bcc" : "",
            "cc" : "",
            "custom" : 
            {
                "body" : "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>You got mail!</title>\n</head>\n<body>\nHey there,\n<p>\n<b>Someone filled out your form, and here's what they said:</b>\n<p>\n[_form_results_]\n</body>\n</html>\n",
                "is_present" : false,
                "subject" : "Idea Submission"
            },
            "from" : "[email]",
            "is_present" : true,
            "replyto" : "[email]",
            "to" : "Info@MyDomain.com"
        }
    },
    "general_settings" : 
    {
        "colorboxautoenabled" : false,
        "colorboxautotime" : 3,
        "colorboxenabled" : false,
        "colorboxname" : "Default",
        "formname" : "Idea Submission",
        "is_appstore" : "0",
        "timezone" : "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "mailchimp" : 
    {
        "apiKey" : "0ef1f58",
        "lists" : 
        [

            {
                "action" : 
                {
                    "subscribe" : 
                    {
                        "condition" : "fields",
                        "fb_name" : "mailing_list",
                        "fb_value" : "Yes"
                    },
                    "unsubscribe" : 
                    {
                        "condition" : "never"
                    }
                },
                "is_present" : true,
                "listid" : "0bfc32032c",
                "merge_tags" : 
                [

                    {
                        "fb_name" : "email_mailing",
                        "field_type" : "email",
                        "isGrouping" : false,
                        "name" : "",
                        "req" : true,
                        "tag" : "EMAIL"
                    },

                    {
                        "fb_name" : "firstname",
                        "field_type" : "text",
                        "isGrouping" : false,
                        "name" : "",
                        "req" : false,
                        "tag" : "FNAME"
                    },

                    {
                        "fb_name" : "lastname",
                        "field_type" : "text",
                        "isGrouping" : false,
                        "name" : "",
                        "req" : false,
                        "tag" : "LNAME"
                    }
                ],
                "name" : "Updates & News",
                "subscribe" : 
                {
                    "double_optin" : true,
                    "email_address_field" : "email_mailing",
                    "email_type_field" : "html",
                    "replace_interests" : true,
                    "send_welcome" : false,
                    "update_existing" : true
                },
                "unsubscribe" : 
                {
                    "delete_member" : false,
                    "email_address_field" : "email_mailing",
                    "send_goodbye" : true,
                    "send_notify" : true
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "payment_settings" : 
    {
        "confirmpayment" : "",
        "currencysymbol" : "",
        "decimals" : 2,
        "fixedprice" : "",
        "invoicelabel" : "",
        "is_present" : false,
        "paymenttype" : "invoice",
        "shopcurrency" : "TRY",
        "usecustomsymbol" : false
    },
    "redirect_settings" : 
    {
        "confirmpage" : "<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html dir=\"ltr\" lang=\"en\">\n<head>\n<title>Success!</title>\n<meta charset=\"utf-8\">\n<style type=\"text/css\">\nbody {background: #f9f9f9;padding-left: 110px;padding-top: 70px; padding-right: 20px;max-width:700px;font-family: Helvetica, Arial;}\np{font-size: 16px;font-weight: bold;color: #666;}\nh1{font-size: 60px; !important;color: #ccc !important;margin:0px;}\nh2{font-size: 28px !important;color: #666 ! important;margin: 0px; border-bottom: 1px dotted #00A2FF; padding-bottom:3px;}\ntd {font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 30px;  color: #666 !important; margin: 0px;border-bottom: 1px solid #e9e9e9;}\ntd:first-child {font-size: 13px !important; font-weight:bold; color: #333 !important; vertical-align:text-top; min-width:100px; padding-right:5px;}\n</style>\n</head>\n<body>\n<h1>Thanks! </h1>\n<h2>The form is on its way.</h2>\n<p>Here&rsquo;s what was sent:</p>\n<div>[_form_results_]</div>\n</body>\n</html>\n",
        "gotopage" : "http://www.MyDomain.com/success/",
        "inline" : "<center><h2>Thank you!</h2>\n<p>We received your form</p></center>",
        "type" : "gotopage"
    },
    "uid" : "a67968bef1ba64039314ab953a1ce923",
    "validation_report" : "in_line"
},
"rules":{"firstname":{"label":"Name","fieldtype":"text","required":true,"maxlength":"25"},"lastname":{"fieldtype":"text","required":true,"maxlength":"25"},"email":{"email":true,"label":"Email","fieldtype":"email","required":true,"equalTo":"email_verification","label_equal":"Confirm Email","maxlength":"254"},"form_of_id":{"label":"Social Security #, Driver&#39;s License, ID or Other","fieldtype":"text","required":true},"streetaddress":{"label":"Address","fieldtype":"text","required":true},"city":{"fieldtype":"text","required":true,"maxlength":"100"},"zip_code":{"fieldtype":"text","required":true,"maxlength":"25"},"state_province":{"fieldtype":"text","required":true,"maxlength":"50"},"country":{"fieldtype":"text","required":true},"phonenumber":{"phone":"phoneUS","label":"Phone Number (Optional)","fieldtype":"tel"},
"payment_rules":{},
"application_version":"Web Form Builder (OSX), build 2.1.4944"
}
```

uid.php:

```
<?php

$txt = false;

if( file_exists( 'form.cfg.dat' ) )
    $txt = file_get_contents( 'form.cfg.dat' );
else if ( file_exists( 'form.cfg.php' ) )
    $txt = file_get_contents( 'form.cfg.php' );

if( $txt === false ) {
    echo 'null';
    exit(0);
}

$config = json_decode( substr( $txt, strpos( $txt, "{" ) ), true );

if( isset( $config['settings'] ) &&
    isset( $config['settings']['uid'] ) ) {

        echo $config['settings']['uid'];

} else {

    echo 'null';
}

?>
```

Idea Submission.html (I have changed sensitive material & got rid of some unnecessary code for this post):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <!-- Start of the headers for CoffeeCup Web Form Builder -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="common/js/form_init.js" data-name=""
    id="form_init_script">
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme/blue_pad/css/default.css?version=884"
    id="theme" />
    <!-- End of the headers for CoffeeCup Web Form Builder -->
    <title>
      Idea Submission
    </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Start of the body content for CoffeeCup Web Form Builder -->
    <form id="docContainer" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="../Idea%20Submission.php"
    novalidate="novalidate" class="fb-toplabel fb-100-item-column selected-object"
    style="width: 650px; " data-form="manual_iframe">
      <div id="fb-form-header1" class="fb-form-header" style="padding-bottom: 30px; padding-top: 20px; padding-left: 35px; height: 1px; ">
        <a id="fb-link-logo1" class="fb-link-logo" href="" target="_blank"><img alt="Alternative text" title="Alternative text" id="fb-logo1" class="fb-logo" src="common/images/image_default.png" style="display: none; "/></a>
      </div>
      <div id="section1" class="section">
        <div id="column1" class="column ui-sortable">
          <div style="display:none; min-height:2332px;" id="fb_confirm_inline">
          </div>
          <div style="display:none;" id="fb_error_report">
          </div>
          <div id="item13" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="opacity: 1; ">
            <div class="fb-header fb-item-alignment-center">
              <h2 style="display: inline; color: rgb(8, 2, 0); ">
                Submit
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item14" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="opacity: 1; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 25px; ">
            <div class="fb-static-text fb-item-alignment-center">
              <p style="font-style: italic; ">
                Hello! Welcome to our submission page!
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item50" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 25px; opacity: 1; padding-top: 20px; ">
            <div class="fb-static-text fb-item-alignment-center">
              <p style="font-weight: bold; ">
                Please only upload submission per form.
                <BR>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item51" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 25px; opacity: 1; ">
            <div class="fb-static-text fb-item-alignment-center">
              <p>
                You may come back as many times as you want.
                <BR>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item1" class="fb-item fb-33-item-column" style="opacity: 1; padding-bottom: 5px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item1_label_0" style="display: inline; ">Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item1_text_1" maxlength="25" placeholder="First"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="FirstName" required autofocus/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item2" class="fb-item fb-66-item-column" style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 33px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item2_label_0" style="display: none; "></label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item2_text_1" maxlength="25" placeholder="Last"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="LastName" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item9" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; opacity: 1; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item9_label_0">Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="email" id="item9_email_1" maxlength="254" placeholder="you@domain.com"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="email" required/>
              <div class="fb-hint" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; ">
                We will contact you by this email address.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label style="color: rgb(0, 113, 188); ">Confirm Email</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="email" id="item9_email_1_verification" maxlength="254" placeholder=""
              autocomplete="off" data-hint="" name="email_verification" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item22" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="opacity: 1; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item22_label_0" style="display: inline; ">Social Security #, Driver&#39;s License, ID or Other</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item22_text_1" maxlength="254" placeholder="" autocomplete="off"
              data-hint="" name="Form_Of_ID" required/>
              <div class="fb-hint" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; ">
                <BR>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item3" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item3_label_0" style="display: inline; ">Address</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item3_text_1" maxlength="254" placeholder="Address Line 1"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="StreetAddress" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item5" class="fb-item fb-33-item-column" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 1px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item5_label_0" style="display: none; "></label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item5_text_1" maxlength="100" placeholder="City"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="City" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item6" class="fb-item fb-33-item-column" style="opacity: 1; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-right: 1px; padding-left: 2px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item6_label_0" style="display: none; "></label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item6_text_1" maxlength="25" placeholder="Postal / Zip Code"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="Zip_Code" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item27" class="fb-item fb-33-item-column" style="opacity: 1; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 2px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item27_label_0" style="display: none; "></label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item27_text_1" maxlength="50" placeholder="State/Province"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="State_Province" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item28" class="fb-item fb-50-item-column" style="opacity: 1; padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 115px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item28_label_0" style="display: none; "></label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item28_text_1" maxlength="254" placeholder="Country"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="Country" required/>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item19" class="fb-item fb-66-item-column" style="padding-top: 0px; opacity: 1; padding-bottom: 10px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item19_label_0" style="display: inline; ">Phone Number (Optional)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-phone">
              <input type="tel" id="item19_tel_1" data-hint="" name="PhoneNumber" placeholder="890-123-4567"
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="item32" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="padding-top: 0px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item32_label_0" style="display: inline; ">Would You Like To Join Our Mailing List?</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-dropdown">
              <select id="item32_select_1" data-hint="" name="Mailing_List" required>
                <option selected id="item32_0_option" value="">
                  Choose one
                </option>
                <option id="item32_1_option" value="Yes">
                  Yes
                </option>
                <option id="item32_2_option" value="No">
                  No
                </option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-hint" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; ">
              Stay caught up on all the awesome things happening with the site and company.
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item34" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item34_label_0" style="display: inline; ">Email For Mailing List</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="email" id="item34_email_1" maxlength="25" placeholder="you@domain.com"
              autocomplete="on" data-hint="" name="email_mailing" required/>
              <div class="fb-hint" style="color: rgb(136, 136, 136); font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; ">
                The address you would like are updates sent to, if signing up for the
                mailing list. It is a required field, but if mark &quot;no&quot; above
                you will not be added to list.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item35" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="opacity: 1; padding-bottom: 0px; ">
            <div class="fb-grouplabel">
              <label id="item35_label_0" style="display: inline; ">How&#39;d You Find Out About Us? (Optional)</label>
            </div>
            <div class="fb-input-box">
              <input type="text" id="item35_text_1" maxlength="254" placeholder="ie. Friend, Google Search, Blog..."
              autocomplete="off" data-hint="" name="HowFound" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="item52" class="fb-item fb-100-item-column" style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-right: 0px; padding-left: 25px; opacity: 1; padding-top: 20px; ">
            <div class="fb-static-text fb-item-alignment-center">
              <p style="font-style: italic; ">
                Thanks for being a member!
                <BR>
                <BR>
                We guarantee to keep all your info and idea materials confidential.
                <BR>
                We will never look at the content of your uploaded files until you inform
                us to do so.
                <BR>
                <BR>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="fb-captcha_control" class="fb-captcha fb-item-alignment-center"
      style="cursor: default; display: block; ">
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var RecaptchaOptions = { theme : 'clean' };
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6Lc368kSAAAAALIQElOa6ig3G3PwwicRRKHM6gUK">
        </script>
        <noscript>
          <iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=6Lc368kSAAAAALIQElOa6ig3G3PwwicRRKHM6gUK"
          height="300" width="500" style="border:none;">
          </iframe>
          <br>
          <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40"></textarea>
          <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field" value="manual_challenge">
        </noscript>
      </div>
      <div id="fb-submit-button-div" class="fb-item-alignment-left fb-footer"
      style="min-height: 1px; ">
        <input type="submit" class="fb-button-special" id="fb-submit-button" data-regular=""
        style="" value="Submit" />
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="fb_form_custom_html" />
      <input type="hidden" name="fb_form_embedded" />
      <input type="hidden" id="fb_js_enable" name="fb_js_enable" />
    </form>
    <!-- End of the body content for CoffeeCup Web Form Builder -->
  </body>

</html>
```

THANKS SOOOOOOO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maby not the most secure way to do it but since your form and wordpress are seperate, you can set the userid in a $_SESSION from the WordPress header and catch that session at your form page.

For WordPress something like:

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();    
$_SESSION['WP']['userId'] = get_userdata( $current_user->ID);
```

And catch it on your form page with:

```
<input type="hidden" name="fb_form_user_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['WP']['userId']; ?>" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do I just put that input line for the hidden field on the html or does it need to be anywhere else also? Will it automatically submit the value with the rest of the data under fb_form_user_id? I placed the first code for global current...in the header of the pages.  THANKS!

Comment: You can put that hidden input field in your generated HTML form. Place it inside the <form></form> tags. You can retrieve that value with an php code like $_POST['fb_form_user_id'];

Comment: The best response I've gotten is by posting <?php global $current_user;
      get_currentuserinfo();

      echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
?> in the header.  It prints the correct user info in the header (did as a test to make sure was getting values), but if I try to grab the info of $current_user->ID in the html form I only get the print out of $current_user->ID not the actual user values.  Does it have to do w/ it being iFrame on the page and not being engrained within the wordpress theme page.

Comment: Joey have you seen my other comment? Still stuck.

Comment: Hi Brad, what you have to do is put the UserID value in a SESSION. Direct into the form is not going to work indeed. With the SESSION you can grap the SESSION value on any other page on that domain. So the SESSION part is really important. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for continuously bothering you but I posted: <?php
session_start();
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();    
$_SESSION['WP']['userId'] = get_userdata( $current_user->ID);
$_SESSION['WP']['userLogin'] = get_userdata( $current_user->user_login);
?>
In the header at the top, under: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

Comment: My hidden fields on the form are: Then my hidden fields are:  <input type="hidden" name="User_ID" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['WP']['userId']; ?>"
      />
      <input type="hidden" name="User_Login" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['WP']['userLogin']; ?>"
      />  I am still just getting an echo in the database of the statements: "<?php echo $_SESSION['WP']['userId']; ?>"
<?php echo $_SESSION['WP']['userLogin']; ?>" I am a real newbie so am just getting what I can from Google...am I a lost cause on this?

Comment: Hi Brad, my guess is that the Form page is not a PHP page right? I think that is why you get the echo in the value attribute. Change the extension of you html form file, to a .php file, like Submission.php.

Comment: Now as a PHP instead of an html it shows the uploaded columns as blank instead.  It knows there should be something uploaded for the id and login sections, but now there the echo of the statement is gone and no values are sent.

Comment: If you still have this problem, send us a URL so we can see whats going wrong.

Comment: Joey, I definitely still need help.  I can't give access to the page here since it is member protected and don't want to place the login info on this board.  If you could email me at info@neighborlyinteractive.com I'll send you a login.  THANKS!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `get_current_user_id()` function to retrieve the current userID in Wordpress, or 0 if the user is not logged in - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_user_id

That said, you will need to call it from within the Wordpress context, and it looks as though your code may not be doing that. Any of the [Wordpress template pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Stepping_Into_Templates) will load the necessary classes and functions to use the Wordpress codex.